# How can I reproduce the formatting in this image?

Tags: spacing, formatting

How can I recreate the following using LaTeX? I'm not interested in the actual writing, I just want the same formatting that allows me to make use of the full A4 page with the bullet points.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fmtcount,multido,lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\geometry{
  vmargin=0.1in,
  left=0pt,% Because you're only using a bulleted list
  right=0.15in
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[nosep]
  \multido{\iA=1+1}{100}{\item \Ordinalstringnum{\iA} item}
  \lipsum[1-3]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```